# Org agenda daily grid view showing wrong date

Tags: org-agenda, org-super-agenda

I am trying to configure a daily agenda grid view like shown below, but for some reason it keeps showing 3 days in the past instead of the current date (at the time of posting this, it is Saturday, 16 January).

```
Wednesday    13 January 2021

 Today
               6:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               8:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              10:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              12:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              14:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              16:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  personal:   16:12...... Closed:     DONE Clean litter box
              18:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              20:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  wgu:        22:00...... Deadline:   DONE Recreate virtual lab environment because I am a dumbass.
              22:00...... ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Interestingly, when I open the calendar it defaults to the wrong date, but it does show "today" as having the correct date. See the bottom of this picture: [image: image here]

Creating a new journal entry also uses the correct date.

I'm not really sure why I can't get my agenda grid to show today's date.

My config is as follows:

```el
(use-package! org-super-agenda
  :hook (after-init . org-super-agenda-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-agenda-time-grid (quote ((daily today) (600 800 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000 2200) "......" "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"))
        org-agenda-include-deadlines t
        org-agenda-include-diary t
        org-agenda-block-separator nil
        org-agenda-compact-blocks t
        org-agenda-start-with-log-mode t
        org-deadline-warning-days 4
        calendar-latitude 34.034520
        calendar-longitude -84.456010
        calendar-location-name "Marietta, GA")
  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(( "z" "Super view"
                                       ((agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 'day)
                                                    (org-super-agenda-groups
                                                     '((:name "Today"
                                                        :time-grid t
                                                        :date today
                                                        :scheduled today
                                                        :order 1)
                                                       (:name "Clocked Today"
                                                        :log t)))))
                                        (alltodo "" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Let's get some shit done ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
                                                     (org-super-agenda-groups
                                                     '((:name "Due today"
                                                        :deadline today
                                                        :order 1)
                                                       (:name "Important"
                                                        :tag "important"
                                                        :order 1)
                                                       (:name "Overdue"
                                                        :deadline past
                                                        :scheduled past
                                                        :order 1)
                                                       (:name "Daily Habits"
                                                        :tag "daily"
                                                        :order 1)
                                                       (:name "Habits"
                                                        :habit t
                                                        :order 2)
                                                       (:name "Due soon"
                                                        :deadline future
                                                        :order 2)
                                                       (:name "Working on"
                                                        :todo "STARTED"
                                                        :order 3)
                                                       (:name "Next to do"
                                                        :todo "NEXT"
                                                        :order 4)
                                                       (:name "Quickies"
                                                        :effort< "0:30"
                                                        :order 5)
                                                       (:discard (:tag("bible")))
                                                       (:name "Projects"
                                                        :children todo
                                                        :order 6)
                                                       (:discard (:anything t))))
                                        )))))))
```

Comment: Do you have items in your agenda for today's date?

Comment: I do, yes. I have at least one item scheduled each day.

Comment: Long shot, I know, but does your computer know the correct date? If you execute `date` on the command line,  does it show today's date?

Comment: If you remove `org-super-agenda` does it show correctly?

Comment: Yes, `date` shows the correct date on my system.
No, removing `org-super-agenda` does not change anything. The day span still shows the date as three days behind (Friday, when today is now Monday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late to the party but I had the same issue and solved it following the configuration [here](https://www.rousette.org.uk/archives/doom-emacs-tweaks-org-journal-and-org-super-agenda/). The trick is to specify the agenda starting day by adding `org-agenda-start-day` to your initial configuration, like so :

```lisp
(use-package! org-super-agenda
    ;; ...
    :config
    (setq org-agenda-start-day nil  ; today
          ;; ...
    ))
```

Comment: I ended up finding this solution yesterday. Thanks for posting it here :) It worked for me.